# Android app EditText color is gone

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have this EditText

```
<EditText
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:id="@+id/messageBodyField"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Message..."
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sendButton"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sendButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"/>
```

And it was working fine. After few updates on Android Studio and the android library after running the app this is what I get:

[image]

As you can see there is no textColor and I cant see the text although I defined the color as black. Another weird thing is that I dont see Copy, cut, paste options there when I selected the text. Their text color also became transparent. 
Any idea on how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Can you try restarting your Android Studio?

Comment: I did. I actually upgraded my Android Studio to 2.0 just now and nothing changed.

Comment: Yeah that is strange; can you try if you don't already do this, wrap your edittext in a TextInputLayout from the support library?

Comment: I have another EditText in another activity in TextInputLayout and it has the same problem. The funny thing is that it doesnt apply to all edittexts. Some Activities EditText works without any issues. This is getting really weird..

Comment: Try changing @android:color to @color/ or write the hex code there itself, as in android:textColor="#000000"

Comment: I already tried that and it doesn't work. I am really curious why the default android color for copy and cut beside that select all is changed. I tried it on another phone and same result.

Comment: I have done pretty much everything I could think of and I still see the same problem. This is getting really weird!